# Iterate a STL set till the second last index

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want to check the difference of two consecutive elements of set so I want to iterate it till the second last element

This is the code written by me

```
for(auto i=s.begin();i!=s.end()-1;i++)
{
  if(s[*i+1]-s[*i]!=1)
  {
     cout<<s[*i]+1<<endl;
     check=true;
     break;
  }
}
```

but this code is giving me errors answer subtraction is not allowed in iterators or no '-' is recognized so can anybody help me with that

Comment: Please paste the exact text of the error message. Also `s[*i+1]-s[*i]` is not how you use iterators. Also, it would be helpful if you showed an input/output example.

Answer (score 0):

`+` and `-` only work on random access iterators. Instead you can use `std::prev` and `std::next` to get the previous and next iterators into a `std::set`.

Also, your usage of the iterators is incorrect, e.g. `s[*i]` is not the value of the element pointed at by `i`. Instead, you have to just write `*i`.

So your code can be written like this:

```
for(auto i = s.begin(), second_last = std::prev(s.end()); i != second_last; ++i)
{
  if(*std::next(i) - *i != 1)
  {
    std::cout << *i + 1 << std::endl; 
    // ...
  }
}
```

Also, this loop will invoke undefined behavior if the set is empty, since the value of `second_last` will be an invalid iterator. So you can do a check for that as well:

```
if (not s.empty())
{
  // ... the above loop
}
```

Comment: I suspect that there's a good chance the compiler won't be able to optimise the call `std::prev(s.end())` on each iteration. So it may be preferrable to cache it in a variable. Should also probably check whether the set is empty.

Comment: @eerorika Yeah, you're probably right about `prev`. Also added the check for an empty set, thanks. (The syntax highlighting is hilarious now :p).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to have two iterator stepping through the set, one of them one position behind the other.

[CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) has an example implementation of `adjacent_find` which does this.

Note that however you do it, your code needs to check that the set has more than one element in it. Both your code and @cigiens code will do the wrong thing when given a set with only one element.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If the set has only one element, then the loop will never be [entered](https://godbolt.org/z/sG8MoP), which seems correct. Did you mean it does the wrong thing with 0 elements? That is true.